# Precedence between non-data descriptor and instance entry in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor

In the paragraph "Descriptor Protocol" of [“Descriptor HowTo Guide"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) of the Python 3.6 documentation there is written

> If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a
>   non-data descriptor, the dictionary entry takes precedence

Maybe I understand something wrong but why does the non-data descriptor has precedence over the instance entry in this example

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
        print( "__get__ is called" )
        return self.__dict__[self.name]


    def __set_name__( self, owner, name ):
        print( "__set_name__ is called" )
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__[name] = "Hello World"

d = Descriptor()

class MyClass:
    data = d

instance_of = MyClass()
instance_of.d = "Goodbye"

print()
print( instance_of.data )
```

I expected that `Goodbye` will be outputted. However there was outputted `Hello World`.

Comment: 1. It’s helpful to *show* the output. 2. Did you mean `instance_of.data = “Goodbye”`? 3. And also `print(instance_of.data)`?

Comment: You haven’t fixed every typo. See 2. Once you do so you will get Goodbye and your question will therefore be redundant.

Comment: You've mixed up `data` and `d`. You're not assigning to the attribute you're trying to read. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: This is more than a typo. This is a misunderstanding of what the is meant by the "name" of a descriptor in the documentation. See the use of the new [`__set_name__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) method in the example.

Comment: @Dunes I’m not sure it is. Neither name set in the descriptor instance is the same as either attribute name on the other instance.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I believe op thinks using `__set_name__` means that python will set the `name` attribute of the descriptor as `d` and will be able to introspect the descriptor when setting the name `d` on the instance.

Comment: Well maybe, but we’d have to wait for them to confirm, and it’s unclear where they’d get that idea. Again note that they’re **not** the same as the attribute names. I assumed that was just a way to rename away from `__set__`.

Comment: Sure, it's not clear exactly what OP thinks. But I can definitely see how they might have been confused over the multiple uses of "name". The quoted documentation talks about names of descriptors and his descriptor example has an attribute name and a `__set_name__` method. Neither of which are what is meant by the name of a descriptor in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That is not is what is meant by "name". Here the "name" refers to the name in the class `__dict__` and in the instance `__dict__`, and *not* any name attribute the descriptor may have. See the following example for when the class descriptor gets overridden.

```
from pprint import pprint

class Descriptor:
    def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
        return "class"

class MyClass:
    data = Descriptor()

obj = MyClass()
# get the data descriptor's value
print(obj.data) # prints "class"

# set an instance attribute with the same name
obj.data = "instance"
print(obj.data) # prints "instance"

# print the variables of both class and instance
# -- both contain the name "data"
pprint(vars(MyClass)) # prints
# mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
#               '__doc__': None,
#               '__module__': '__main__',
#               '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
#               'data': <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x034BF1B0>})
print(vars(obj)) # prints
# {'data': 'instance'}

# delete the instance attribute and the descriptor becomes visible again
del obj.data
print(obj.data) # prints "class" again
```

Comment: In this section there is written "If an object defines both __get__() and __set__(), it is considered a data descriptor" So your interpretation does not make sense. data is not a descriptor because it does not define at least __get__.

Comment: It is a descriptor as it *does* define `__get__`. But it is a non-data descriptor rather than a data descriptor. Data descriptors also define `__set__`. You also seem to mixed up over precedences. Non-data descriptors (without `__set__`) are overruled by the instance's `__dict__`. Whereas data descriptors (with `__set__`) overrule the instance's `__dict__`.

Comment: The most common non-data descriptors are functions. This allows them to return bound functions when getting them off of an instance, but allows you to monkey-patch an object by setting a value to the same name.

Comment: I am sorry but using the general terms of programming data nothing defines. It is the class Descriptor or at least the object d that defines this method.